# Unable to connect to remote using ipv6: ping6: UDP connect: No route to host

Tags: networking, ipv6, ping

thought I'd try asking here since I don't know where else to turn to.

Simply, I am trying to ping/SSH my remote server from my local machine using ipv6 but it keeps failing. Executing `ping6` for my remote server or Google's DNS eg `2001:4860:4860:0:0:0:0:8888` just yields `ping6: UDP connect: No route to host` error.

It must be a configuration problem with either my laptop's or router's settings but I can't seem to find a clear answer what exactly. ipv4 pinging works fine. I switched from my wifi to phone's hotspot and it produces the same error.

I am using MBP M1 2021 with Monterey.

Comment: Is this in a business setting? If not, superuser.com is the appropriate place for it. Anyway, you will have to include more detail, such as how things are configured, and what documentation your ISP provides on IPv6. As the question stands now, all we can say is that you're probably right that it doesn't work.

Comment: I am working on servers that I intend to use for business - does that count? I dont know if there is a lot of dichotomy here. Yes, I can provide details but as I said I dont know even where to look for answers so it's quite hard to give those unless asked. I cant even ping6 my router so it could be an issue with my laptop settings.

Comment: If you don't know where to start, I would suggest learning about how IPv6 is deployed, so that you're actually able to verify the pieces that are in a IPv6 deployment. This site is for IT professionals, so we generally expect that you are able to describe the problem you're facing.

Comment: So how one does become a "professional" if not by learning? But thanks for contributing. I asked at superuser https://superuser.com/questions/1807305/unable-to-connect-using-ipv6-with-macos-ping6-udp-connect-no-route-to-host

Comment: Thing is, when the question literally is **Things are not working, and I want them to**, you are not very likely to receive much response - neither here or on superuser. Have you verified that your ISP deploys IPv6? How is things configured? What equipment do you have? You include *no* information, so there's no way we could offer any answers.

Comment: I have tried various things but why bother overloading the post with unnecessary details? If somebody asks me a question about my domain, I can easily give a rundown of steps to debug the problem without being condescending

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148341/discussion-between-vidarlo-and-teemuk).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently while debugging the problem, I altered my IPv6 network settings (as advised somewhere else) and when I connected through my phone hotspot the internet worked but the IPv6 was wrong (the IPv6 configuration should be set to automatic).

Apparently, my broadband ISP has IPv6 disabled whereas my mobile ISP doesn't. Hope this will help others!